# Modal title and text is not visible (Bootstrap)

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have created a simple model, and when I click I can see it pops out but the heading and the paragraph are not being visible. I can see an empty model which is weird. I read the Bootstrap documentation but still, what am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

```
<div class="container text-center">
    <h1 class="display-3 text-center">Explore</h1>
    <p class="text-center">Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Iste architecto itaque quis dolorem accusamus provident?</p>

    <button class="btn btn-outline-light" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Read More</button>

    <div class="modal" id="myModal">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title">Connect with Us!</h5>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Pariatur error vitae ullam quisquam magni! Id voluptate quod quaerat molestias quas?</p>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
    $('#myModal').on('show.bs.modal', function(){
        $('#myModal').modal('show')
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Your js event is useless, you are telling him: "when you open the modal, open the modal", it calls an infinite loop, just remove the js script

Comment: getting the same result after removing it.

Comment: Do you have an error in the console ? Have you included bootstrap.js & jquery ? I copied your code including bootstrap and it works fine

Comment: nothing in the console I have triple checked and bootstrap and jquery is included as well.

Comment: Look at this fiddle, it's exactly your code: https://jsfiddle.net/Alex197/n2jcud56/2/

Comment: thanks Alex, I'll see where else might be the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Text was not being visible due to both white, upon changing the color it is visible. Sorry to bother you :)